# Chrome transformation is always HTMLDocument, no matter XSL output method

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, xslt

XSL said output method is text.
In firefox transformToDocument return xml document with root element **transformiix:result** because output method is text (same with xml output method.
But in Chrome result is - HTML document.

**file** is XML and it's from local machine but XSL is from web server.

What I am doing wrong?

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadConfigurationFromFile(file) {
xsl = loadXMLDoc("xsl/configuration.xsl");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    // code for IE
xml = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(reader.result, "text/xml");
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
    {
        resultDocument = xml.transformNode(xsl);
    }
    // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    {   
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml,document);
}
```

In FireFox resultDocument is XMLDocument because output is text.
It would be the same if output is xml.
And it would be HTMLDocument in case otuput is html.

```
<transformiix:result> **RESULT OF TRANSFORMATION AS TEXT** </transformiix:result>
```

In Chrome resultDocument is always HTMLDocument, no matter which output is in XSL file (html|xml|text).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://wwww.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <head>
    <pre>
       **RESULT OF TRANSFORMATION AS TEXT**
    </pre>
  </head>
</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor

Comment: Your text says "output method is text", yet your XSLT snippet has `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`. And why `version="2.0"` for XSLT? No browser supports that. Does the `body` of the document that Chrome returns not contain the result you want, much like the text content of the `transformiix:result` does it for Firefox?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Honnen, You think browser wouldn't know translate with old 1.0 version?
Translate works good in meaning transformation itself. Problem is only that in Chrome I get HTMLDocument as result of a transformation and in FireFox I get XMLDocument as result, which is good because XSL output method="text" gives XMLDocument as result which is fine with me.

Comment: @Kay, as I said, I have XSL output method="text". In FireFox (see link) You get XMLDocument as result of transformation. It has only one root element and result of transformation as text as children of that root element. That is how it should works. But in Chrome I get HTMLDocument and entity as first child, HTML element as second child. That HTML element has also 2 childs, HEAD and BODY and both has one child element. BODY has PRE element as child where is my result of transformation (output method="text")

Comment: Unfortunately that API is not very portable and has never been standardized so extract the text from the HTML document as you have to extract it from the XML document.  As for the XSLT version, by using `version="2.0"`, you are putting the XSLT 1 processors browsers have into https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#forwards processing mode that way and might miss out on error messages you would normally get. That is nothing related to your API use but certainly not a good way of using XSLT in the browser where it is hard to debug anyway.

Comment: @Honnen, funny, I changed in 1.0 (before I used that XSL on server side, in Java) and in FireFox works - fine. In Chrome I get: 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty
</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body></html>